# Better performance for the shortest paths in undirected unweighted graph

Tags: graph-theory, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I got the undirected unweighted graph. Where every node represents one city. Every city produces one type of grocery (does not have to be unique).
Then you will have on the input a number of type groceries which has to be delivered to every city. You can transport every grocery separately and it has to be the shortest way. The distance between every node is 1.

Actually, I'm using BFS for every node. But there should be a better solution.

```
Example: 
INPUT:

5(number of nodes) 5(number of edges) 
4(number of groceries) 3(required number of groceries in every city)
0 1 3 2 1 ( city(node number) has grocery 0->0 1->1 2->3 3->2 4->1)
0 1 (edges)
2 1 (edges)
2 3 (edges)
3 0 (edges)
4 3 (edges)

OUTPUT:
11 (total distance)
2(total distance for town) 0 1 2 (groceries in the city)
2 1 0 3
2 3 1 2
2 2 0 1
3 1 2 0
```

Comment: You can do one BFS per grocery type, if there are not many.